# Derive the posterior density of $\Theta$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Suppose that $X\sim \operatorname{Unif}(0,\theta)$ and assume a priori that $\Theta\sim Ga(2,1)$, that is $f_\Theta(\theta)\propto\theta e^{-\theta}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(\theta)$.

**Exercise:** Derive the posterior density of $\Theta$.

*What I've tried:* I know that $$f_{\Theta\mid X}(\theta\mid x) = \dfrac{f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)}{\displaystyle\int f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)d\theta}\propto f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)$$ What I'm unsure about is how to write $f_{\Theta\mid X}(\theta\mid x)\propto f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)\,f_\Theta(\theta)$, because this product of functions has two indicator functions in it, both with a different argument. We have (sort of?) $f_{\Theta\mid X}(\theta, x) \propto \dfrac{1}{\theta}\mathbb{1}_{(0,\theta)}(x)\,\theta e^{-\theta}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(\theta)$ which makes me very uncomfortable. Furthermore when asked to give the posterior distribution, I'm not if I have to supply the entire fraction with the constant, or just the part to which it is proportional.

**Question:** How do I solve this exercise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prior is proportional as a function of $\theta$ to $\theta e^{-\theta} \, d\theta$ on the interval $\theta>0.$

The likelihood is $\dfrac 1 \theta$ on the interval $(X,\infty)$ (and there is no $d\theta$ is this).

Multiplying the two you get $e^{-\theta}\,d\theta$ on the interval $(X,\infty).$

Since $\displaystyle\int_X^\infty e^{-\theta} \, d\theta = e^{-X},$ the posterior distribution is $e^{X-\theta} \, d\theta$ on the interval $(X,\infty).$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you explain why the likelihood is $\dfrac{1}{\theta}$ on the interval $(X,\infty)$ instead on the interval $(0,\theta)$?

Comment: @titusAdam : What would $\text{“}(0,\theta)\text{''}$ mean? You're talking about a function of $\theta$ ‒ something that varies as $\theta$ changes. The value of $\theta$ is different at different points in the domain. But you're saying one endpoint of the domain is $\theta.$ Which value of $\theta$ would that be? Note $\vphantom{\dfrac1{\displaystyle\sum}}$ that the uniform density is $f(x) = \left. \begin{cases} 1/\theta & \text{if } 0<x<\theta, \\ 0 & \text{if } x>\theta. \end{cases} \right\} $ That is a function of with $\theta$ fixed. But the$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$likelihood function is a function of $\theta$ with $x$ fixed. And we have $x\le\theta. \qquad$

Comment: Great explanation thanks!

Comment: One more question; if you would be so kind ;). Why does the posterior distribution equal $e^{X - \theta}$? Suppose $\theta = X$, then $e^{X - \theta} = 1$, right? If $F_\Theta(\theta) = e^{X - \theta}$ is the distribution function that would mean that $F_\Theta(X) = \mathbb{P}(\Theta \leq X) = 1$, while this is impossible.

Comment: @titusAdam : I said $e^{X-\theta} \, d\theta$ for $\theta>X$ is the posterior distribution. Since $d\theta$ is there, the part that precedes $d\theta$ is the density function, not the c.d.f. If you integrate that from $X$ to $\infty,$ you get $1. \qquad$